# Is it possible to test for responsiveness of URL, before redirecting to it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4.

I want to do a redirect, at the end of an Action.

```
return Redirect("http://www.domain1.com");
```

However I would like to test whether this domain works, and if not to redirect to another ie "domain2.com"

Is this possible?

EDIT

```
            try
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        return Redirect("Domain1");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Redirect("Domain2");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Redirect("Domain2");
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  You prob. want to hit the domain and check for a 200 response.  Something like this should get you started.

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://www.google.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Working");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Working");
}
```

Comment: If he is doing it often probably worth creating some sort of RedirectActionResult that takes primary and secondary url

Comment: I notice that the second line will crash for example where the domain is invalid. Also got this with an invalid certificate. Obviously I need to capture these errors before testing whether the return value was 200. Any way to do this?

Comment: Sorted via try catch block, See EDIT

Comment: @SamJolly Good call, the example code given above was not intended to be a "final" solution just to point you in the right direction.